# d3 date format for "Aug. 13, 2015, 7:57 a.m"

Tags: d3.js, time, format

I am using d3 to draw a line graph of values against time.

Sample time:

```
"Aug. 13, 2015, 7:57 a.m"
```

This is what I am using to format this sample date.

```
parseDate  = d3.time.format("%b. %d, %Y, %I:%M %p").parse
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What value are you passing into your parseDate function?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [d3.time.format(specifier)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format) the directive `%p` is expected to be either `AM` or `PM`.

```
var dateStr = "Aug. 13, 2015, 7:57 AM",
    parseDate = d3.time.format("%b. %d, %Y, %I:%M %p").parse

d3.select("#date").text(parseDate(dateStr));
```

```js
var dateStr = "Aug. 13, 2015, 7:57 AM",
    parseDate  = d3.time.format("%b. %d, %Y, %I:%M %p").parse

d3.select("#date").text(parseDate(dateStr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<p id="date"></p>
```